# How to detect onscroll event on an iframe? the iframe's source is of the same domain of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, jquery-events

The plan is not to have a scroll bar to the iframe that I am adding to my page. So the idea to do it as I thought is to have a onscroll function.

So whenever a user scrolls the iframe, I will call this function

```
function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

But I do not know how to detect onscroll event inside an iframe.

PS: the source of the iframe is of the same domain as the page.

My iframe:

```
<iframe id="externalIframe" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="width: 1240px; height: 489px; display:block" src="http://www.example.com/" onload="resizeIframe(this);" onscroll="resizeIframe(this);" onclick="resizeIframe(this)"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4):

JQuery solution:

```
$("#yourFrameId").load(function () {
     var iframe = $("#yourFrameId").contents();

    $(iframe).scroll(function () { 
        //your code here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this snippet. Bind the **onscroll** function on the iframe load event.

```
function getFrameTargetElement(objI)
{
    var objFrame = objI.contentWindow;
    if(window.pageYOffset==undefined)
    {   
        objFrame = (objFrame .document.documentElement) ? objFrame .document.documentElement : objFrame =document.body; 
    }
 //- return computed value
    return objFrame ;
}
$("#externalIframe").load(function (){
    var frame = getFrameTargetElement(document.getElementById("externalIframe"));

    frame.onscroll = function (e) {
         resizeIframe(obj);
    }
});
```

Comment: i get this error when i use the code. it says
getFrameTargetElement is not defined

Comment: added `function getFrameTargetElement()` to get Iframe document.

Answer (score 0):

```
var iframe = angular.element(document.getElementById('terms'));
iframe.load(() => {
    var checkIndex = $scope.stageContent.checkbox.length;   // Take last slot for the scroll check
    checks[checkIndex] = false;

    var iframeDoc = iframe.contents();
    var treshold = iframeDoc.height() - (iframe.height() * 1.5);
    iframeDoc.scroll(() => {
        if (iframeDoc.scrollTop() >= treshold) {
            $timeout(() => {
                checks[checkIndex] = true;
                checkCanContinue();
            });
            iframeDoc.off('scroll');
        }
    });
});
```